# How to simultaneously run multiple window managers (esp. xmonad) for VNC

Tags: gnome, vnc, xmonad, vnc-server, ubuntu-unity

I'll start with a little background. A small project of mine has been to try to use my Android tablet as an external monitor for my laptop using a VNC client (vnc4server). There are two main options for doing this that I have seen. The simplest is to use xrandr and widen the screen, creating a section just for the tablet. However, this can cause some graphics issues if I understand correctly, although it has the benefit of permitting windows to cross displays. The other option is to run a separate desktop session for the VNC server.

I have chosen to go the route of a second desktop as the session can live and die without significantly affecting my main session and can in theory be tailored specifically to the tablet. A little tool called x2vnc allows me to connect to the VNC server in a similar manner to the more popular Synergy and use it like a n external monitor. I also have the nice little benefit of being able to easily and cleanly switch from landscape to portrait using xrandr.

This brings me to my current issue. So far, I have only been able to reliably use plain x-windows. Although this is entirely functional, I would prefer something more complete. Although xstartup examples have been posted for a variety of window managers, none of these seem to run properly. I suspect all of these are for headless systems. Gnome/Unity are each unforgivably slow and seem to conflict with my existing session. I also feel that these are a little too cluttered for my ten inch tablet. On the other hand, Xmonad simply crashes as soon as I try to open a second window in addition to not updating the graphics properly.

I would like to know anything that will lead me in the direction of a better stable desktop environment. This includes configuration tips and alternate window managers.

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-xmonad (recently Unity). My xstartup is plain x-window-manager. I have tried any readily available examples for gnome and xmonad that I have been able to find.

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the window manager code? If you are just trying to change the configuration settings without changing the code, then you should ask on SuperUser.com, ubuntu.stackexchange.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.